# Why Vuetify tables shows inconsistent cells width?

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

In Vue, I have created multiple tables in the same component's template. Those tables all have the same html template, except they use different property of `data ()`. Somehow the column width is inconsistent between them.

```
<template>
    <v-container>
        <h2>Security</h2>
        <hr>
        <v-simple-table>
            <template v-slot:default>
                <tbody>
                <tr v-for="(a, index) in user_info.security_titles"
                    :key="a">
                    <td><strong>{{ a }}</strong></td>
                    <td v-show="user_info.security_data">{{user_info.security_data[index]}}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </template>
        </v-simple-table>
        <br>
        <h2>Connection</h2>
        <hr>
        <v-simple-table>
            <template v-slot:default>
                <tbody>
                <tr v-for="(b, index) in user_info.connection_titles"
                    :key="b">
                    <td> <strong>{{ b }}</strong> </td>
                    <td v-show="user_info.connection_data">{{user_info.connection_data[index]}}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </template>
        </v-simple-table>
        <br>
        <h2>Language</h2>
        <hr>
        <v-simple-table>
            <template v-slot:default>
                <tbody>
                <tr v-for="(c, index) in user_info.language_titles"
                    :key="c">
                    <td> <strong>{{ c }}</strong> </td>
                    <td v-show="user_info.language_data">{{user_info.language_data[index]}}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </template>
        </v-simple-table>
    </v-container>
</template>
```

I have used any style

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A table always tries to fit in the content the most nicely, so if your column contains a row with long text, that column will take up more space.

You can use the width property in your headers to have a fixed width as shown [in the docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#api)

```js
{
  text: string
  value: string
  align?: 'start' | 'center' | 'end'
  sortable?: boolean
  filterable?: boolean
  divider?: boolean
  class?: string | string[]
  width?: string | number
  filter?: (value: any, search: string, item: any) => boolean
  sort?: (a: any, b: any) => number
}
```